# Rhythmbox playing an .asx internet radio file

Tags: 11.04, 10.04, banshee, rhythmbox

I have a problem with playing internet radio.   The stream is http://www.daveramsey.com/radio/home/the_dave_ramsey_show_live.asx It plays in google chrome, and VLC but not Rhythmbox. I want it to play in Rhythmbox because it integrates with Ubuntu better.  How do I get this to play in Rhythmbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't tried Rhythmbox;

*.asx works for me in VLC

and does *NOT* work for me in Banshee (in Natty).

Maybe an extension (perhaps the radio extension) is needed here?

"Error opening stream - could not open stream or playlist"
 and
"File Not Found"

are the messages I get in Banshee.

**EDIT**

[Sound doesn't work in Unity, but does in Ubuntu Classic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41312/rhythmbox-and-banshee-not-playing-in-11-04)

Comment: Yup works in VLC.