# Sound doesn't work in Unity, but does in Ubuntu Classic 

Tags: 11.04, unity, sound, banshee, rhythmbox

I recently updated to 11.04, and it seems rhythmbox broke for me in the update, as well as the new default, banshee. When I try to play a song, the play button changes to a pause button, but nothing plays and the scrollbar detailing the current time of the song doesn't move. It might be a problem with the streamer, but I'm not sure. Has this happened to anyone else?

I've found that it's not just them Banshee and Rhythmbox, no sound works. Also, it only stops working with Unity on -- it works fine with Ubuntu Classic.

Comment: It definitely sounds like a gstreamer problem, but that's very bizarre that switching Unity on or off would have any effect on audio playback.  What is the output of running Banshee from Terminal with the command `banshee --debug` ?

Answer (score 1):

You could also try adding some of the restricted extras that play mp3s

To do that, follow the instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56446/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-restricted-extras).

Then you should be able to play mp3s.