# How do I install the ubuntu-restricted-extras package?

Tags: ubuntu-restricted-extras

I would like to install the restricted extras package, which I didn't select during the install. How can I do that?

---

> [ubuntu-restricted-extras](/questions/tagged/ubuntu-restricted-extras) is a meta-package that installs:
>
> - Support for MP3 and unencrypted DVD playback
> - Microsoft TrueType core fonts
> - Flash plugin
> - codecs for common audio and video files

Comment: If you need [DVD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats/PlayingDVDs) or [Blueray](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats/BluRayAndHDDVD) playback there are some extra steps required.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats/Flash

Comment: `Google Chrome` comes with built in flash player and plays all videos. `Mozilla Firefox` requires installing `flash player` Following link suggests to install Chrome :http://askubuntu.com/questions/79280/how-to-install-chrome-browser-properly-via-command-line

Comment: You need http://askubuntu.com/a/56448/2973

Comment: several additional information: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats

Comment:  whats this 'Flash Plugin' you speak of... 

https://www.adobe.com/products/flashplayer/end-of-life.html

Answer (score 40, accepted):

First, be warned that it might not be legal in some countries, because of software patents.

With that being said, here is how to install it, click here:

[ubuntu-restricted-extras](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/ubuntu-restricted-extras) [image: Install ubuntu-restricted-extras]

Or you can open up a terminal and run the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

Select yes, and you'll have `ubuntu-restricted-extras` installed and working.

Comment: it doesn't work on ubuntu 18.04

Comment: @nicolimo86 That's the version I wanted to do it with too.

Answer (score 9):

I suggest to install **Ubuntu Restricted Extras** through Ubuntu Software Center. It will install all media codecs plus java and flash plugins.

Well I think you need to enable *multiverse* on **Software and Updates** (if you use Ubuntu 12.04, you can access software properties or something like that from Ubuntu Software Center > Edit menu)

[image: enable multiverse]

Then close the Software Center and open **Software Updater** (Update Manager on 12.04) to update the package lists. Alternatively you can run `sudo apt-get update` from Terminal.

After update got completed, open Software Center again and look for Ubuntu restricted extras to install.

[image: Ubuntu restricted extras]

If you still can’t find the package, try `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras` from a Terminal and see if it results in an error.

Comment: I've found the software center but cannot find the icon for Ubuntu retstricted extras?

Comment: @vincent There is no icon just for this it is just a box of tools that is the generic icon for system tools.  you can find it by searching for it by name in the text box in the upper right of the Software Center. If you want to find theses ind of things without knowing their complete name you need to click the bottom left where it says "Show xx Technical Items" to show the hidden items that are usually this kind of software.

Comment: @vincent, as TrailRider mentioned, Ubuntu restricted extras is not an app so there’s no icon for it in Dash or somewhere, you need to search for it inside Ubuntu Software Center. I just edited my answer to add screenshots and more information. I hope it will help.

Comment: @TrailRider thanks a lot, but I think it will be excellent if it can help the question owner. ;)

Answer (score 7):

Just [click this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats) to apt repository.

Or go to software centre and install **Ubuntu-restricted-extras**

Or use apt-get, type in terminal

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```