# How to install Chrome browser properly via command line?

Tags: command-line, google-chrome, software-installation

I am trying to install chrome browser via command line.  I tried this:

```
$ apt-cache search chrome browser
```

The results show that the proper term is "chrome-browser," so I tried that:

```
$ sudo apt-get install chrome-browser
```

And then "Y" for the Y/n question.

But the installation threw errors.  Does someone see anything wrong with the commands I issued?

Answer (score 286, accepted):

Google Chrome is not in the repositories because it is proprietary, however Chromium(the open source platform Chrome is built upon) is.

These are the instructions to install Chrome on a 64 bit Linux distribution as that architecture is the only one Chrome supports.

To install Google Chrome, run the following:

```sh
sudo apt-get install libxss1 libappindicator1 libindicator7
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
sudo apt install ./google-chrome*.deb
```

Installed this way, the package has the name `google-chrome-stable`.

If error messages pop up after running the command `sudo apt install ./google-chrome*.deb` then run the command

```sh
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Comment: `uname -i` gave me `x86_64` but it would seem I needed it to output `amd64` instead.

Comment: I get this an ERROR 404 with these instructions. I installed using @David E. Moore instructions listed below.  Not sure if adding the libxss1 helped with Mr Moore's instruction or not but I did do that before.  This was on a fresh install on 13.10 Unity amd64 install.

Comment: What is the package `libxss1` for? Is this still a requirement?

Comment: I also had to install xdg-utils with
   sudo apt-get install xdg-utils

Comment: libcurl3 is also required.

Comment: This will not update chrome as part of the package manager. It's better to add the repository.

Comment: dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of google-chrome-stable:
 google-chrome-stable depends on libpango1.0-0 (>= 1.22.0); however:
  Package libpango1.0-0 is not installed.

Comment: @James Could you please update this to indicate that google has ended support for 32 bit as of March 2016 from [here](http://www.pcworld.com/article/3010404/browsers/googles-killing-chrome-support-for-32-bit-linux-ubuntu-1204-and-debian-7.html)

Comment: I needed to run the following command to install Chrome 51 on Ubuntu 16: apt-get install libnss3-nssdb fonts-liberation libnspr4 libnss3 libcurl3

Comment: https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_i386.deb returns 404

Comment: @reggie done! :)

Comment: @jeremy31 all taken care of, sorry I missed your comment back in April!!

Comment: I've found using `gdebi-gtk` instead of `sudo dpkg -i google-chrome*.deb` more convenient.  Basically one has to run,  `gksudo gdebi-gtk`, followed by opening the _deb_ file from the menu and the selecting _Install Package_.

Comment: Hello guys, is this command set relevant for Ubuntu 16.04 updated?

Comment: I wish I had enough rep to answer, but there's an easier way. `wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb` and then `sudo apt-get install ./google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb` - that handles everything including dependencies.

Answer (score 109):

As per http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/google_chrome

```
wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add - 
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list'
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable
```

Comment: Finally, this works on ix86 systems, thakns

Comment: This is a great answer to get the standard Google Chrome.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer since it also pulls dependencies.

Comment: after following the steps, when i run the command sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable, "Unable to locate package google-chrome-stable"

Comment: Perhaps you are using a 32-bit Ubuntu when only 64-bit is supported now, as suggested by https://askubuntu.com/a/853130/28107.

Comment: After running the commands above in Ubuntu 20.04, when running `apt upgrade` I get many warnings like this: `Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1`. The error disappears after deleting `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list`

Answer (score 58):

If you really want to install Chrome (not Chromium) using `apt-get` it's possible as explained [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1351541):

- Add google repository to your sources, that is, create a new file under `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` with the following contents:

  ```
  deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
  ```
- Get repository key:

  ```
  wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add -
  ```
- Update your sources:

  ```
  sudo apt-get update
  ```
- And install the package:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable
  ```

Note: instead of `google-chrome-stable` you can also install either `google-chrome-beta` or `google-chrome-unstable` packages from the same repository.

Comment: You said "create a new file under...", but what should I name that file?

Comment: Well, the problem with this is that when you install Chrome, in theory it'll break, because Chrome's postinstall script does this for you... :)

Comment: I'd say that the name of the file isn't really important (not sure about the extension though). I'd name it `google.list`, but it could be `chrome.list` or some other random name not being already used.

Comment: @jrg I decided to give it a try and what I found is that indeed Chrome packaging scripts add a new file under `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`. The result of this is that Chrome installation didn't fail, but `apt-get update` now prints a "duplicate sources.list entry" warning; so, yes, this method shouldn't be used unless you want to fix the sources files later.

Comment: Here are the relevant instructions on the [Google PPA page](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/google_chrome).  Some of the details are now a bit different and so the above answer should be updated accordingly.

Comment: One of the answers here creates the file as well.

Comment: `non-free` should be removed from the PPA file...

Comment: +1 this is much nicer for managing dependency issues.

Comment: This currently works for me(tm)

Answer (score 24):

If you are running a 64 Bit system, then use this:

```
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

then:

```
sudo dpkg -i ./google-chrome*.deb
```

and to finish:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

This is the same as [jrg's](https://askubuntu.com/users/6005/jrg) reply, but you change the i386.deb to amd64.deb.

EDIT:  The past couple of times I have not had to do the install -f.  It seems to have all needed after installing.

Good Luck!!

Comment: Jorge added this to the accepted answer above.  I guess I should of thought of that.  Makes the answer more complete now.

Comment: Is the line `sudo apt-get install -f` really necessary?

Comment: I think my answer is outdated.  I've used the answer above mine (at this time) by @Dale E. Moore and had successful installs.

Comment: Your answer is not outdated.  The **google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb** will remain current (by its namesake) as long as it's being maintained and updated by Google.  On rare occasions, just like any manual install, you might have to use the `install -f` option.  But as of Ubuntu 18.04, it installs the absolute latest Chrome update and configures it to be automatically flagged for regular updates when they are available.  The two commands are the cleanest and easiest method of a fresh install of Google Chrome.

Answer (score 9):

```
wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add - 
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list'
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable
```

that's correct code for ubuntu :)

Answer (score 6):

If you want the official Google Chrome build, you have to download it from here: [Download Google Chrome](http://www.google.com/chrome?platform=linux&hl=en).

I believe only Chromium is in the repository.

Answer (score -6):

If you want Google Chrome, just search it in google. If you want Chromium add this ppa:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chromium-daily/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install chromium-browser
```

And that's it. Enjoy your browser.

Comment: -1, daily builds aren't recommended for anyone other than developers. THIS IS DANGEROUS.

Comment: What PPA should be added? If you cannot answer this question now you can delete your answer, and gain back 2 rep.