# Error when trying to install reader software for Estonian ID card

Tags: apt, software-installation

So my ID software got out-of date. I wanted to update it but it failed to find any updates by itself. So now I removed the old sofware from my computer and tried to install it again and I get this in my terminal:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 estonianidcard : Depends: qdigidoc but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: qesteidutil but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I am using a install script from here: https://installer.id.ee/media/install-scripts/install-esteid-ubuntu.sh
I change the `OPSYS=` line to raring because the source where it tries to fetch my software has raring the latest soft: https://installer.id.ee/media/ubuntu/dists/

So..  where did I go wrong here?

Output:

```
$ apt-cache policy estonianidcard qdigidoc qesteidutil
estonianidcard:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 3.7.2.1310-ubuntu-12-10
  Version table:
     3.7.2.1310-ubuntu-12-10 0
        500 https://installer.id.ee/media/ubuntu/ quantal/main i386 Packages
qdigidoc:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 3.7.2.1198-ubuntu-12-10
  Version table:
     3.7.2.1198-ubuntu-13-04 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     3.7.2.1198-ubuntu-12-10 0
        500 https://installer.id.ee/media/ubuntu/ quantal/main i386 Packages
     0.4.1-0ubuntu1 0
        500 http://ee.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/universe i386 Packages
qesteidutil:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 3.7.2.1079-ubuntu-12-10
  Version table:
     3.7.2.1079-ubuntu-12-10 0
        500 https://installer.id.ee/media/ubuntu/ quantal/main i386 Packages
     0.3.1-0ubuntu2 0
        500 http://ee.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/universe i386 Packages
```

Comment: Allright so the ttf-liberation does not exist anymore, which it wants to install?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Missing font packages in 13.10

Liberation still exists. As all the other font packages do, they just got renamed to be less format specific. The Liberation font from `ttf-liberation` package can now be found in `fonts-liberation`. With 13.10/saucy all the (transitional) `ttf-*` packages were finally dropped, but not the fonts themselves.

## Workaround for broken font dependency

Only the `qesteidutil` package seems to contain the outdated dependency. You could download the package and update the `control` file within the `debian` directory of the package.

Also please check if `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ria-repository.list` really contains the release name you want to download packages for. If not, edit the file and run `sudo apt-get update`. If you still encounter issues, then take a look at [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies)

### Suggestion: build your own packages

Since sources are available, you could rebuild one or all of the packages. The packages however are incompatible to the Debian guidelines as they all seem to be missing copyright information and may be more (see the [packaging guide](http://packaging.ubuntu.com/html/) for information on how to get started and how Debian compliant packages should look like).

## A closer look at the setup script

The script is used to write distribution specific repository files to `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ria-repository.list`, which deviates from the default naming convention for these files and implies that the script should be run after each release upgrade, unless you know what to fix. It will leave you without installable packages for saucy, as they do not exist currently. The script also fetches and installs the repository key from the key server.

If you build your own signed packages and want to distribute them, you would need to modify these parts of the script. The best solution would be a Ubuntu PPA, given that the source code is really Open Source and free to distribute (should be, as I can see a lot of files containing the LGPL license text when browsing for example https://svn.eesti.ee/projektid/idkaart_public/branches/3.7.2/).

## Summary

I know this looks like I am just complaining or talking you into packaging, but I am confident that these little issues can be sorted out.

Answer (score -3):

Your problem is mainly that you are mixing repositories. You are trying to install quantal packages in a Saucy system. **This you shouldn't happen!** The `https://installer.id.ee/media/ubuntu/dists/` shows that they do have packages for saucy ready, so you should change to that repository. If you paid for the service, you must contact *their* support if you got any troubles.

Remove any `quantal` reference from your sources and add saucy's which they have packages ready.

To do the first run this:

```
sudo sed -i '/quantal/d' /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list
```

and add this to your source.list:

```
deb https://installer.id.ee/media/ubuntu/ saucy main
```

You must make sure that you have the `apt-transport-https` package installed.

Comment: No it's actually raring one I am trying to install.
In here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/245769/problem-installing-id-card-software
I had a different Ubuntu version also and the solution I as given worked.

Comment: The output I got from you says otherwise. Sorry, but you have `saucy` and try to install `quantal`, that's the undeniable truth.

Comment: @Braiam The undeniable thruth is that the repository contains raring packages. :P

Comment: @LiveWireBT mm... He's mixing saucy (his system is a saucy installation) and quantal repos, that's the only truth. The liberation font is just an extra and has nothing to do with the original question.

Comment: @LiveWireBT I didn't said that, my proposed solution is definitive and involves the less hassle for the OP and it reads as following: *Remove the quantal repository you have, then either wait for upstream to release a saucy version of the package or downgrade to raring*. For the downvote, for all I care is that it could be the same person that dv both answers. I know my solution is a-OK in the current circumstances and should be the most effective and permanent solution.

Comment: @LiveWireBT and they have package for saucy now https://installer.id.ee/media/ubuntu/dists/saucy/main/

Comment: @Braiam I think that the OP has already upgraded his system to Trusty... :)

Comment: @RaduRădeanu please, **do not assume.**