# How do I fix unsatisfied dependency and install Chrome in 13.10?

Tags: installation, google-chrome, 13.10

When I try to install chrome I get the error message

```
dependency is not satisfiable: lib32gcc1 (>= 1.4.1.1).
```

What do I do to install chrome (version 30.0.1599.101-1)?

Comment: Chromium Package version available for Ubuntu 13.10 is "29.0.1547.65" [packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=saucy&searchon=names&keywords=chromium). You could have tried with other source. But can be installed with `sudo apt-get install chromium-brower` or with Software Center

Comment: See [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/79280/how-to-install-chrome-browser-properly-via-command-line), worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

someone at Google goof up and put 64 bit dependencies in the 32 bit architecture. So basically we have to wait on them to fix it. But you can install chromium in the software center.

Comment: It seems like the issues has already been fixed, although the fixed version hasn't been released yet. If you run `apt-get install google-chrome-beta`, it doesn't complain about unment dependencies at all. However, there may be other bugs revieling their ugly heads (since this is a beta).

Answer (score -1):

Try installing the dependencies.

Run this command:

```
sudo apt-get install lib32gcc1
```

Do you get any errors now?