# Google Chrome doesn't install

Tags: google-chrome

I've just recently installed Ubuntu alongside Windows using file mount audit.
I'm just using a 32 bit Ubuntu and downloaded a 32 bit chrome for it but couldn't
install it, I always receive " bad architecture " message each  time I install it.
I already checked  if I got 32 bit chrome and yes it is. Does the issue have something 
to do with the way I installed Ubuntu?

Comment: If you try (just to see what happens not as a solution) to install Chromium from the repositories does it give a similar error ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can install it through the command line. Open the Terminal and:

```
 sudo apt-get install libxss1
 wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_i386.deb
 sudo dpkg -i google-chrome*.deb
```

source: [How to install Chrome browser properly via command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/79280/how-to-install-chrome-browser-properly-via-command-line)

Answer (score 0):

If you only need something like chrome, you can usually get Chromium from the Ubuntu Software Center or Muon Discover. It's good if you just need a google browser. It has all of the same features as Chrome, I believe. It's a really nice alternative.