# Can't launch Google Chrome in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: google-chrome

I have installed the 14.04 LTS in clean. then I use wget the chrome.deb for 64 bit from Google and dpkg -i *.deb to install the chrome in my Ubuntu 14.04,however I can't launch it and get errors as below, could you please help me to solve this problem?

```
$ google-chrome
[2697:2697:0616/211443:ERROR:process_singleton_linux.cc(394)] readlink failed: no authority
[2697:2697:0616/211443:ERROR:process_singleton_linux.cc(240)] readlink(/home/frank/.config/google-chrome/SingletonLock) failed: no authority
[2697:2697:0616/211443:ERROR:process_singleton_linux.cc(240)] readlink(/home/frank/.config/google-chrome/SingletonLock) failed: no authority
[2697:2697:0616/211443:ERROR:process_singleton_linux.cc(264)] Failed to create /home/frank/.config/google-chrome/SingletonLock: no authority
[2697:2697:0616/211443:ERROR:process_singleton_linux.cc(394)] readlink failed: no authority
[2697:2697:0616/211443:ERROR:process_singleton_linux.cc(240)] readlink(/home/frank/.config/google-chrome/SingletonLock) failed: no authority
[2697:2697:0616/211443:ERROR:chrome_browser_main.cc(1209)] Failed to create a ProcessSingleton for your profile directory. This means that running multiple instances would start multiple browser processes rather than opening a new window in the existing process. Aborting now to avoid profile corruption.
```

Comment: why don't you try this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/79280/how-to-install-chrome-browser-properly-via-command-line

Comment: I had already tried, the result is the same, still same error, don't know what's wrong.

Comment: Try with `sudo`

Comment: Try reinstalling it.

Comment: Delete your /home/frank/.config/google-chrome/ directory and try to start again. Worked for me...

Comment: This should be a duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/q/618478/367165

Comment: @A.B. I'd argue it goes the other way...

Comment: [This](http://askubuntu.com/a/510063/426113) worked perfectly for me just the other day.

Answer (score 2):

Correct the ownership, assuming `frank` is your username:

```
chown -R frank:frank /home/frank
```

and the permissions for all folders:

```
find /home/frank -type d -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 775
```

`775` - These are the default permissions when you create a new folder.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open a terminal and run `sudo -i nautilus`
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>
3. Navigate to `.config/` and right click on `google-chrome`. Select permissions, and ensure you are the owner.
4. Run chrome.

Comment: Can this damage anything?

Answer (score 0):

I run 14.04 x64 and it works just fine, from the repos. I personally prefer to install programs from repos, since it's much easier to remember to update it. Delete the google-chrome you have now, and install it from Google's repos(taken from http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/google_chrome)

Setup the key with:

```
 wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add -
```

Enable the repo with:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list'
```

Then update the repos with:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then finally install Google Chrome with:

```
sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable
```

Alternatively you could install the beta with

```
sudo apt-get install google-chrome-beta
```

Or the unstable with:

```
sudo apt-get install google-chrome-unstable
```