# Google Chrome fails to start

Tags: permissions, google-chrome, chromium, home-directory

This is the error I get when I run `google-chrome` in the terminal:

```
[0505/065554:ERROR:nss_util.cc(94)] Failed to create
/home/pipi/.pki/nssdb directory. [0505/065554:ERROR:nss_util.cc(94)]
Failed to create /home/pipi/.pki/nssdb directory.
[3545:3545:0505/065557:ERROR:nss_util.cc(94)] Failed to create
/home/pipi/.pki/nssdb directory.
[3545:3545:0505/065558:ERROR:process_singleton_posix.cc(417)] readlink
failed: Permission denied
[3545:3545:0505/065558:ERROR:process_singleton_posix.cc(253)]
readlink(/home/pipi/.config/google-chrome/SingletonLock) failed:
Permission denied
[3545:3545:0505/065558:ERROR:process_singleton_posix.cc(253)]
readlink(/home/pipi/.config/google-chrome/SingletonLock) failed:
Permission denied
[3545:3545:0505/065558:ERROR:process_singleton_posix.cc(277)] Failed
to create /home/pipi/.config/google-chrome/SingletonLock: Permission
denied [3545:3545:0505/065558:ERROR:process_singleton_posix.cc(417)]
readlink failed: Permission denied
[3545:3545:0505/065558:ERROR:process_singleton_posix.cc(253)]
readlink(/home/pipi/.config/google-chrome/SingletonLock) failed:
Permission denied
[3545:3545:0505/065558:ERROR:chrome_browser_main.cc(1213)] Failed to
create a ProcessSingleton for your profile directory. This means that
running multiple instances would start multiple browser processes
rather than opening a new window in the existing process. Aborting now
to avoid profile corruption.
```

Comment: Vote for reopen: The [answer](http://askubuntu.com/q/484128/367165) addresses a similar problem. However, it concerns other directories. Perhaps the problem is the same, but the error messages are different. This is confusing for the questioner. In addition, there is no accepted answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Correct the ownership, assuming `pipi` is your username:

```
chown -R pipi:pipi /home/pipi
```

and the permissions for all folders:

```
find /home/pipi -type d -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 775
```

`775` - These are the default permissions when you create a new folder.

Comment: Good one!  +1 :p

Comment: So you need both write and execute permissions? `Execute` should be enough.

Answer (score 2):

A lot of people have said that removing `~/.gtkrc-2.0` would do the trick. And sometimes permission would be the culprit. I had the same problem but neither helped! Uninstalling and installing chrome also doesn't help.

Turns out, when Chrome crashes sometimes the **User Data Directory** can get corrupted. So to fix it I did the following:

1. Uninstall chrome `apt-get purge google-chrome-stable`
2. Install chrome http://chrome.google.com
3. Remove the cache and configuration folders. 
   `rm -rf /home/<<your username>>/.config/google-chrome/`
   and `rm -rf /home/<<your username>>/.cache/google-chrome/`
4. Start Chrome and enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

1. Delete `google-chrome` or `chromium` folder in `.config`

   ```
   rm -rf ~/.config/google-chrome/
   ```
2. Rename `google-chrome-backup` or `chromium-backup`

   ```
   mv ~/.config/chromium-backup chromium
   ```
3. Restart Chrome or Chromium.