# Chromium works fine, but it crashes my 16.04 system

Tags: 16.04, chromium, crash

Whenever I use Chromium my computer crashes after some time. Like, if I just open it once, and then close, then my computer crashes later on and I have to restart my computer.

There are lot of questions on how to stop Chromium from crashing. Chromium has no problem whatsoever when I use it. The problem I am having is that my Ubuntu 16.04 crashes if I use Chromium at least once.

Edit:

I tried opening it through the terminal. It didn't open. This is the error I got:

```
[3875:3875:1231/134723.051486:ERROR:process_singleton_posix.cc(433)] readlink failed: Permission denied (13)
[3875:3875:1231/134723.051538:ERROR:process_singleton_posix.cc(256)] readlink(/home/albin/.config/chromium/SingletonLock) failed: Permission denied (13)
[3875:3875:1231/134723.051568:ERROR:process_singleton_posix.cc(256)] readlink(/home/albin/.config/chromium/SingletonLock) failed: Permission denied (13)
[3875:3875:1231/134723.051584:ERROR:process_singleton_posix.cc(280)] Failed to create /home/albin/.config/chromium/SingletonLock: Permission denied (13)
[3875:3875:1231/134723.051613:ERROR:process_singleton_posix.cc(433)] readlink failed: Permission denied (13)
[3875:3875:1231/134723.051628:ERROR:process_singleton_posix.cc(256)] readlink(/home/albin/.config/chromium/SingletonLock) failed: Permission denied (13)
[3875:3875:1231/134723.051707:ERROR:chrome_browser_main.cc(1496)] Failed to create a ProcessSingleton for your profile directory. This means that running multiple instances would start multiple browser processes rather than opening a new window in the existing process. Aborting now to avoid profile corruption.
[3875:3909:1231/134723.391975:ERROR:browser_gpu_channel_host_factory.cc(107)] > Failed to launch GPU process.
```

This is the error I get when I try to run it with `sudo`:

```
[4111:4111:1231/135149.919427:ERROR:zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(88)] Running as root without --no-sandbox is not supported. See https://crbug.com/638180.
```

Edit 2:

I tried the answer given in this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/618478/google-chrome-fails-to-start). It solved most of the issues I guess... but this is what I get now:

```
ATTENTION: default value of option force_s3tc_enable overridden by environment.
[5106:5106:1231/142053.572447:ERROR:navigation_entry_screenshot_manager.cc(135)] Invalid entry with unique id: 1
```

Comment: Have you tried opening chromium from terminal.
Edit the question and post your output from terminal

Comment: It says it's not installed. I installed chromium from Ubuntu Software

Comment: @AlbinDoesGames Are you talking about the Chromium web browser? In Ubuntu, the command to run the Chromium browser is `chromium-browser`, not `chromium`. Might that account for how you were unable to run it from the command-line? If so, you should be able to run it from a terminal by typing `chromium-browser`, to obtain the information requested here, which you can then edit your question to provide. Based on your description, I am not really sure if it will be useful, since you said the effect was to destabilize your system rather than to crash immediately. Still, it's worth a try, I think.

Comment: yeah @EliahKagan I tried chromium-browser in the terminal. I also added error message I got( I have edited and added it in the question)

Comment: @AlbinDoesGames Thanks. It appears to be the same problem as described in [that other question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/618478/google-chrome-fails-to-start). The solutions posted there should help.

Comment: @EliahKagan now chromium starts but I still get an ATTENTION after I ran the command. Should I add it in the question?

Comment: @EliahKagan I have added the ATTENTION message.

Comment: I see that ATTENTION message everytime I run Chromium-browser, should it bother me?