# Ubuntu14.04 Google-chrome unable to launch

Tags: 14.04, google-chrome

When I try to launch google-chrome, I get the following message:

```
Failed to create a ProcessSingleton for your profile directory. 
This means that running multiple instances would start multiple browser processes
rather than opening a new window in the existing process. 
Aborting now to avoid profile corruption.
```

I tried to uninstall and reinstall Chrome following the advice here [How to install Chrome browser properly via command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/79280/how-to-install-chrome-browser-properly-via-command-line), which did not solve my problem.

*How should I proceed?*

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! ;-) Could you please review my edits and for the future, use [Ctrl][K] or backticks "`" to highlight code and improve readability?

Answer (score 0):

Your .config and .pki folder in home directory might be assigned with root permission.

Type `sudo chown -R {username}:{username} ~/.config ~/.pki`

Note: Replace {username} with your username that you are logged on in.