# Downloading Google Chrome (armhf?)

Tags: google-chrome

I've been using this question ([How to install Chrome browser properly via command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/79280/how-to-install-chrome-browser-properly-via-command-line)) to try to install google chrome.
I get to the very last command,

```
sudo dpkg -i google-chrome*.deb
```

And I get a message "package architecture (amd) does not match system (armhf).
I'm sorry if this is a noobish question, but I can't find a fix myself. Any pointers or advice?

Comment: Did you ever check this?

http://askubuntu.com/questions/79280/how-to-install-chrome-browser-properly-via-command-line

Comment: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/374/how-do-i-install-google-chrome

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install Google Chrome?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/510056/how-to-install-google-chrome)

Comment: For Debian users: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/51633/56469

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Its weird to install the genuine Google Chrome, as the normal Chrome browser for Linux is the Chromium Web Browser.Available via command line and software center.

But for genuine Google Chrome its odd...if you do get Google Chrome you will be able to access normally limited streams such as Netflix.

You will need to go to https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/desktop/index.html. I have included a link for you to click of for easy access. You will need to click the download button and select your OS type for the download.

Once you have finished your download you will need to go to your downloads folder and double the download for chrome.

It will reroute you to the software center, where you must download Google-Chrome-Stable.Once it has downloaded you now have Google Chrome, just search your dash home for it and lock it to your launcher.

Comment: I don't believe you'll find an armhf build linked to from the official Google site? :(

Answer (score 3):

Chrome doesn't support armhf systems, but the community open source Chromium does. Do a one liner `sudo apt-get install chromium-browser` to install Chromium, which, to the average user, is an exact replica of Google Chrome (logins and everything are supported). If you get an error after this, something saying that a dependency is missing, do `sudo apt-get install -f`.

Using raspberry pi, maybe? Full browsers tend to run slowly on raspberry pi's, but enjoy it if you can get it to run!

Answer (score 2):

Google Chrome on your architecture (armhf) is problematic because of licensing issues with ARM and bugs with ARM's proprietary drivers. See issue 457511 --https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=457511

The Samsung ARM Chromebooks are able to operate with some complex workarounds that are beyond installation with a simple Debian package.

If you want to try building Chromium yourself -- see --

http://malideveloper.arm.com/resources/drivers/mali-t6xx-gpu-user-space-drivers/

Answer (score 2):

You should download Vivaldi or Midori browser which are also best alternatives for linux. First of all you need to run the following command to download wget:

```
sudo apt install wget
```

And then you should run the following command:

```
wget https://downloads.vivaldi.com/stable/vivaldi-stable_2.11.1811.47-1_armhf.deb
```

Or to download Midori, just use this command

```
sudo apt install midori
```

Comment: You should add the `dpkg -i ...` command to the Vivaldi part of your answer.