# Google Chrome install error

Tags: google-chrome

I'm new to Ubuntu and not a programmer, although I am definitely learning a few things on these boards...
I am running 14.04 and trying to download Google Chrome, but I get this error when I try to download it in the software center:

```
Dependency is not satisfiable: libappindicator1

Error
```

Any ideas? I can give you more information if necessary.
Thanks!

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `apt-cache policy libappindicator1`

Comment: Have you added a PPA? Have you downloaded a deb file? What was the installation command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I installed Ubuntu for the first time, I had the same dependency problems as you while installing the Chrome `.deb` file (before running `update`)

Therefore, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to go to a terminal and run:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

... as that will install required dependencies.

Then just install `chrome`  from the Software Centre.

Comment: I don't know who is the downvoter...but I too got same dependecy problem while installing `.deb` file...I solved by updating...

Comment: A down vote may or may not hurt,but I appreciate it when there is an explanation=)

Comment: @Rachel32  As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)! **;-)**

Comment: If you add an explanation why this should work, I'll come back and upvote...  This answer is a fish.  Teach people to fish for themselves, please...  **:P :-)**

Comment: @Fabby done..my level best

Comment: An edit *and* an upvote!  **;-)**

Answer (score 3):

You need to run first this command:

```
sudo apt-get install libxss1 libappindicator1 libindicator7
```

Follow this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/79284/322687) to install chrome

Answer (score 0):

This should be fixed by running

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

When you install 3rd party packages, the dependencies do not install automatically.