# Unable to fix unmet dependencies

Tags: package-management, dependencies

I installed (not successfully) [chrome 32-bit](https://askubuntu.com/a/79284/476890)  and didn't know that my OS type was 64-bit. I tried to fix it with this command `sudo apt-get -f install` but there was an [error](http://pastebin.com/PJYNzbSx).

Every time I install a package, for example, `flashplugin-installer` or `gdebi`, it shows an error:

```
$ sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libc6 : Breaks: locales (< 2.19)
 libc6:i386 : Recommends: libc6-i686:i386
              Breaks: locales (< 2.19)
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

$ sudo apt-get install gdebi

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gdebi : Depends: gdebi-core (= 0.9.5.5+nmu1) but it is not going to be installed
         Recommends: libgtk2-perl but it is not going to be installed
 libc6 : Breaks: locales (< 2.19)
 libc6:i386 : Recommends: libc6-i686:i386
              Breaks: locales (< 2.19)
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

How do I fix this? I'm new at Linux.

---

**Edit:**

> **Next**, run:
>
> `sudo apt-get clean`
>   `sudo apt-get update`

Well I am stuck at that before purging and downgrading libc6 on mchid's answer. I am having this [error](http://pastebin.com/GkexbVNb), and mchid suggested this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41605/trouble-downloading-packages-list-due-to-a-hash-sum-mismatch-error) but the solutions didn't solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**

I found out that a pin-priority of 1001 will allow downgrades of this priority set so you can downgrade all existing Ubuntu packages that were mistakenly installed because of the Kali Repo. This should really help to fix things and should also prevent dependency issues in the future.

**First**, edit your /etc/apt/preferences file before you do anything else.

Run the following commands:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/preferences
```

Now, copy and paste the following into the file:

```
Package: *
Pin: origin ppa.launchpad.net
Pin-Priority: 1001

Package: *
Pin: origin ph.archive.ubuntu.com
Pin-Priority: 1001

Package: *
Pin: origin security.ubuntu.com
Pin-Priority: 1001

Package: *
Pin: origin extras.ubuntu.com
Pin-Priority: 1001

Package: *
Pin: origin repo.kali.org
Pin-Priority: 600

Package: *
Pin: origin extras.ubuntu.com
Pin-Priority: 1001

Package: *
Pin: origin security.kali.org
Pin-Priority: 600

Package: *
Pin: origin http.kali.org
Pin-Priority: 600
```

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>o</kbd> and then press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> to save the file. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd> to exit nano.

**Next**, run:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
```

**Then**, purge libc6-dbg and downgrade libc6:i386, libc6-dev, and libc6:

```
sudo dpkg -P libc6-dbg
apt-get download libc6-udeb=2.19-0ubuntu6 libc6-dev=2.19-0ubuntu6.6 libc6=2.19-0ubuntu6.6:i386
sudo dpkg -i libc6_2.19-0ubuntu6.6_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libc6-dev_2.19-0ubuntu6.6_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libc6_2.19-0ubuntu6.6_i386.deb
```

Also, downgrade gdebi:

```
sudo apt-get install gdebi=0.9.5.3ubuntu2
```

If all goes well, run the following commands. If not, please post your errors.

---

**To install google-chrome-stable:**

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo dpkg -P google-chrome-stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Please post any errors. If there are no errors, continue:

```
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
sudo gdebi google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

`gdebi` will handle all the dependencies for you.

Comment: Ok, on `sudo apt-get update`, still having that `hash sum mismatch`....
And can you explain this? `apt-get download libc6-udeb=2.19-0ubuntu6 libc6-dev=2.19-0ubuntu6.6 libc6=2.19-0ubuntu6.6:i386` does this download 32 bit I guess? Still having an [error](http://pastebin.com/i4dM96MX) about that.

Comment: @newbieguy I think the i386 error is related to the version and not the arch, however, I see no harm in removing it but I figured I'd only recommend that if there was an error after trying to install the correct version. So, you could go ahead and purge the i386 version and skip the download and install of the i386 version as well. As for the hash sum error, that needs to be fixed first. You can try opening software sources and swi

Comment: @newbieguy Switching to the main server instead of the regional one you are currently using. Don't worry about getting one for Kali at the moment as the versions we are working with are all ubuntu.

Comment: @newbieguy alternatively, try setting your DNS in network manager to 8.8.4.4 or 8.8.8.8 in case your ISP is caching your DNS requests and causing the issue.

Comment: Done, no unmet dependencies. I just reinstalled Ubuntu, hehe...