# Unable to fix unmet dependencies ubuntu server

Tags: apt, package-management, ssh, dependencies

i am not able to install some packages, i got this error, i already tried all clean and -f options with apt-get. also tried this [Unable to fix unmet dependencies](https://askubuntu.com/questions/704151/unable-to-fix-unmet-dependencies) but it did not work for me. Running latest ubuntu server version. only SSH acces to it. Please help :) Very new to Ubuntu.

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 build-essential : Depends: libc6-dev but it is not going to be installed or
                            libc-dev
                   Depends: g++ (>= 4:4.4.3) but it is not going to be installed
 libpcap-dev : Depends: libpcap0.8-dev but it is not going to be installed
 libpq-dev : Depends: krb5-multidev but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: comerr-dev but it is not going to be installed
 libsqlite3-dev : Depends: libc6-dev but it is not going to be installed
 postgresql : Depends: postgresql-9.3 but it is not going to be installed
 zlib1g-dev : Depends: libc6-dev but it is not going to be installed or
                       libc-dev
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

--
THE GIVEN OUTPUT :

```
build-essential:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 11.6ubuntu6
  Version table:
     11.6ubuntu6 0
        500 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
libc6-dev:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.19-0ubuntu6.6
  Version table:
     2.19-0ubuntu6.6 0
        500 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packa                             ges
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main amd64 Packag                             es
     2.19-0ubuntu6 0
        500 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
libc-dev:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
g++:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 4:4.8.2-1ubuntu6
  Version table:
     4:4.8.2-1ubuntu6 0
        500 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
libpcap-dev:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.5.3-2
  Version table:
     1.5.3-2 0
        500 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
libpcap0.8-dev:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.5.3-2
  Version table:
     1.5.3-2 0
        500 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
libpq-dev:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 9.3.10-0ubuntu0.14.04
  Version table:
     9.3.10-0ubuntu0.14.04 0
        500 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packa                             ges
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main amd64 Packag                             es
     9.3.4-1 0
        500 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
krb5-multidev:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.12+dfsg-2ubuntu5.2
  Version table:
     1.12+dfsg-2ubuntu5.2 0
        500 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packa                             ges
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main amd64 Packag                             es
     1.12+dfsg-2ubuntu4 0
        500 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
comerr-dev:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.1-1.42.9-3ubuntu1.3
  Version table:
     2.1-1.42.9-3ubuntu1.3 0
        500 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packa                             ges
     2.1-1.42.9-3ubuntu1.2 0
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main amd64 Packag                             es
     2.1-1.42.9-3ubuntu1 0
        500 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
libsqlite3-dev:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 3.8.2-1ubuntu2.1
  Version table:
     3.8.2-1ubuntu2.1 0
        500 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packa                             ges
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main amd64 Packag                             es
     3.8.2-1ubuntu2 0
        500 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
postgresql:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 9.3+154ubuntu1
  Version table:
     9.3+154ubuntu1 0
        500 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packa                             ges
     9.3+154 0
        500 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
postgresql-9.3:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 9.3.10-0ubuntu0.14.04
  Version table:
     9.3.10-0ubuntu0.14.04 0
        500 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packa                             ges
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main amd64 Packag                             es
     9.3.4-1 0
        500 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
zlib1g-dev:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:1.2.8.dfsg-1ubuntu1
  Version table:
     1:1.2.8.dfsg-1ubuntu1 0
        500 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt-get update` as suggested in the answer you linked? If that didn't work, the issue seems to be with the repos you've enabled. Can you list out which repos you've enabled in `/etc/apt/sources.list`?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the output of `apt-cache policy build-essential libc6-dev libc-dev g++ libpcap-dev libpcap0.8-dev libpq-dev krb5-multidev comerr-dev libsqlite3-dev postgresql postgresql-9.3 zlib1g-dev`. Then leave a short comment when you're done to notify me, please.