# Unable to fix unmet dependencies problem (after SDK installation via .sh)

Tags: dependencies, display-resolution, ubuntu-sdk, opencl, sdk

I was installing opencl drivers and SDK from [this](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/sdk-for-opencl-gsg) site using shell scripts.
I got unmet dependencies error. I tried the solution given in [Unable to fix unmet dependencies](https://askubuntu.com/questions/704151/unable-to-fix-unmet-dependencies), but it did not work for me. I am very new to Ubuntu.Kindly help.
Output for

```
root@mcw-01:/home/user01/Desktop#sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... failed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libicu-dev: Depends: libicu52 (=52.1-3ubuntu0.4) but 52.1-8 is installed
libicu52: Depends: libstdc++6 (>=4.9) but 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3 is installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
```

Furthermore, this problen also changed the display resolution. only low screen resolution (640 x 480) is available.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are running 14.04, but the page only says the SDK install script has been tested on 16.04. It is probably not compatible with 14.04 (it seems to install a version of `libicu52` that depends on a version of `libstdc++6` which is higher than the one in 14.04).

The only solution I see is to install it on a 16.04 system.