# Can't apt-get google-chrome-stable

Tags: apt, package-management, google-chrome

I seem to have gotten my sources for Google Chrome into a bad state and am unable to `apt-get install google-chrome-stable` (it errors with`E: Unable to locate package google-chrome-stable`).

I have added what I think is the appropriate source:

```
dan@MyDesktop:~$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list 
deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
```

Furthermore, it looks like the entry for the `google-chrome-stable` package is getting hooked up because after I run `apt-get update` I see:

```
dan@MyDesktop:~$ cat /var/lib/apt/lists/dl.google.com_linux_chrome_deb_dists_stable_main_binary-amd64_Packages | grep google-chrome-stable
Package: google-chrome-stable
Filename: pool/main/g/google-chrome-stable/google-chrome-stable_54.0.2840.100-1_amd64.deb
```

Despite this fact, `apt-get` still isn't finding the package:

```
dan@MyDesktop:~$ apt-cache policy google-chrome-stable
N: Unable to locate package google-chrome-stable
```

Adding more information about the `apt-get` cache:

```
dan@MyDesktop:~$ apt-cache policy | grep google
500 http://dl.google.com/linux/musicmanager/deb/ stable/main i386 Packages
    release v=1.0,o=Google, Inc.,a=stable,n=stable,l=Google,c=main
    origin dl.google.com
500 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable/main amd64 Packages
    release v=1.0,o=Google, Inc.,a=stable,n=stable,l=Google,c=main
    origin dl.google.com
```

Adding more information about user identity:

```
dan@MyDesktop:~$ uname -a
Linux MyDesktop 3.13.0-101-generic #148-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 20 22:09:17 UTC 2016 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: What is the output of `apt-cache policy google-chrome-stable`?

Comment: What is the output of `apt-cache policy`?

Comment: @Anwar - I'll be updating the question to answer these types of comments so as to avoid extended discussion in the "Comments" section.

Comment: Yes. That is the preferred way actually. Nice

Comment: What is the output of `uname -a`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I've identified your problem. You're using 32-bit Ubuntu but google chrome is only available for 64-bit architecture. Thus by default when you want to install it, it will show

> `E: Unable to locate package google-chrome-stable`

So, the solution is using a 64-bit Ubuntu OS.

Here is the news http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/01/google-chrome-linux-32-bit-discontinued. However, it seems you can also use Chromium browser which supports 32-bit arch still. Also you can use Opera browser which is based on Chrome mostly.

Comment: Ah, that's frustrating! I'm on a 64-bit system so I have no idea why I would have installed 32-bit Ubuntu...gah! Good looking out!

Comment: @DanForbes happens! If you can install 64-bit, install it. Otherwise I also included two other options. Chromium or Opera

Comment: Yeah, I have Chromium installed already. Thanks for the help!