# apt: error while loading shared libraries:

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

I am very new to linux. When trying to install any software with apt, i get the error

```
apt-get: error while loading shared libraries: libapt-pkg.so.4.12: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

[apt error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8GIi.png)

I think the problem is that one of apt dependencies **libapt-pkg.so.4.12** doesn't exist.

When i type `dpkg -l` i can see that i have **libapt-pkg5.0:amd64**. Is this a newer version of what apt needs?

How can i make apt to use the right package version?

Thanks!

Comment: What version of Ubuntu you are using?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 17.10

Comment: Really sorry, I am not expert in this matter. However I tried to look into the matter and I found that `libapt-pkg.so.4.12` is a package for `trusty i.e Ubuntu 14.04`. For Ubuntu 17.10 `libapt-pkg5.0` is the right package. Can you tell us when this problem started to appear? That is to say, do you know what caused the apt to break down?

Comment: I was trying to install chrome using some instructions i found online.  Somewhere along the line, i must have broken apt. Can i somehow remove the apt package and re-install it? Or somehow reset the OS?

Comment: @SomeGuyFortune if you try that you won't like what you see! And where are those instructions for chrome you speak of?

Comment: I did try a lot of funny things when trying to get more familiar with linux. I must have broken something. I think this was the tutorial. https://askubuntu.com/questions/79280/how-to-install-chrome-browser-properly-via-command-line