# Banshee doesn't play songs

Tags: banshee

I am a new Ubuntu user as of this morning. I put a few songs into Banshee to test it out. Initially it didn't work, but after a reboot, it played music until I closed the app. Some time later I tried it again, and this time it doesn't play anything. Have been trying it a while now.

As far as I can tell the songs are there. They were donloaded to the hardrive and worked once today for a brief time. I don't know what the "package for the mp3 installed (ubuntu-restricted-extras)." sorry - I am a bit of a novice. Spent my computing life being coddled by Mac.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have the songs in another partition that you have to mount when you start the PC. Are the songs even there?. Did you try looking for the songs with Banshee just in case they were moved?. Do you have the package for the mp3 installed (ubuntu-restricted-extras). Are the songs in the actual hard drive or a pen drive/removable device?

Comment: Luis -as far as I can tell the songs are there. They were donloaded to the hardrive and worked once today for a brief time. I don't know what the "package for the mp3 installed (ubuntu-restricted-extras)." sorry - a bit of a novice here. Spent my computing life being coddled by Mac -

Comment: open Software Center and look for "restricted". A package will appear called "Ubuntu Restricted Extras". Install that if you have not already. After which you might want to check if Banshee has the volume on full or minor stuff like that.

Comment: Try this and edit your question with what happens: http://askubuntu.com/questions/56446/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-restricted-extras

Comment: What do you mean with 'I don't know what the "package for the mp3 installed (ubuntu-restricted-extras)."'? If your song seek bar doesn't seem to move, and instead of reading the time elapsed/left reads "Idle", then try running `pulseaudio --kill` - this will kill your sound server and it will start again automatically. Report back whether this works or not.

Answer (score 1):

Open terminal with `Ctrl+alt+T` and put this command:

`sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras`

This solution solves the problem for me.

Comment: Can you tell the OP how to run it using a terminal? The OP states they are a novice.

Comment: Amazing, it worked!