# mp4 video's from web site will not play

Tags: video

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install ubuntu-restricted extras](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56446/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-restricted-extras)

I can't get video files to play in either Chromium or Firefox, when I try and load them from the web site this is what I get  "The video could not be loaded, either because the server or network failed or because the format is not supported: http://media.woodsmith.com/etip/2012/02/woodsmithtipsintro_02162012.mp4"

Answer (score 0):

install vlc plugin for mozilla

```
 sudo apt-get install mozilla-plugin-vlc
```

Comment: I changed default browser to Firefox, this Did not work, sometimes video will start but will not get past introduction.  I use to be able to play files in chromium without trouble but won't even load?

Comment: I did the following addition and all works now in Chromium & Firefox      "sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras"