# How can I permanently sync my videos in ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: software-recommendation, video

So some of my videos are out of sync and although I can temporarily fix it (I use VLC) it does not fix this issue permanently.

Is there a way to fix this? Maybe software (from the software center) that will allow me to change the sync? (I have Dell Mini Inspiron 10v, so it may struggle with some software).

Comment: Hello UbuntuFan, did you already install Ubuntu Restricted Extras from the Software Center (or in a terminal by dropping sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras) as mentioned in this answer? http://askubuntu.com/a/56448/9598 Your issue sounds more like a codecs problem. If you already installed try reinstalling, in certain cases the correct installation of restricted extras solves the majority of the issues for multimedia playback. Please inform on your results. Thank you

Comment: Yer I do have them, I installed when i Installed the OS, its defiantly the video thats the problem, as it happens on my main computer as well with the same video files

Answer (score 0):

You will need to remultiplex the video and audio streams in a video container file to increase or decrease delay. Tools like avconv (no GUI), mkvmerge (GUI called mmg), and avidemuxer (GUI) can achieve that.