# How to make graphics / video appear on websites that use Adobe Flash?

Tags: 13.04, flash

I installed version 13.04 on my Dell Studio XPS laptop and have been using it fine. I explain to my wife that we need to switch to UBUNTU and stop using Windows. She agrees, so I install Ubuntu 13.04 on my Dell Inspiron 530 Desktop with new NVidia 610 graphics card. And it all looks great. She sits a the computer to start working and the first page she goes to in Firefox is our timeshare to book something and the map of locations does not show up. Instead it has a link saying we need to install Adobe Flash Player.

When I click on the link ot take me to Adobe download page and recognizes I'm running linux. It suggests several options or versions of linux based flash players. When I click download a box pops up wanting to know what application I want to use to run the application. With NO Application listed ?????? This is not helpful and I don't know what to do? Any help would be great. I tried searches to no avail. Wife is not impressed with Ubuntu already!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can download and install the Adobe Flash Player from the Ubuntu Software Center.

Click on your Dash icon,(topmost left icon on your MenuBar) type in Ubuntu Software Centre. Inside the applicaion you could search for Adobe Flash Plugin.

Alternatively I am providing this link, just click on it.

[Adobe Flash Player](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/ubuntu-restricted-extras)

The Flash player plugin is present in the following package.You can have a look at it

[ubuntu restricted extras](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56446/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-restricted-extras)

Thank You!