# ubuntu 14.04 wont play amazon prime videos in fierfox anymore

Tags: firefox, amazon

Before last update it worked. Now I get a "unsupported browser" message.

[image]

Comment: Can you upload a screenshot to Imgur or something and then [edit] your answer with a link to it?

Comment: - Check the about page for the user agent.

Comment: @Zacharee1 Its there now.

Comment: Hmm. I would try what @Rinzwind said. It's possible that was changed.

Comment: @peter make it an answer please Not an edit into the question

Comment: I looked at the about page(i think that what it was).... linked a new screen shot of the relevant part. Looks like they want html5 player is not available for firefox.

Answer (score 2):

It Looks like they want html5 player and that  is not available for firefox:

[image]

Comment: Related (HTML5 for FF): http://askubuntu.com/questions/475351/firefox-html5-video-support and http://askubuntu.com/questions/389437/how-do-i-get-html5-h-264-video-working-on-firefox

Answer (score 1):

You can switch to Google Chrome (not Chromium, since it doesn't include the Widevine content decryption plugin) and use native HTML5 player to watch prime videos. The only downside is you can't manually set the video quality to HD, but it's auto-set by determining your bandwidth.

FYI: I didn't update anything and it stopped working for me with the same message on 2015/10/21 (Arch Linux, FF 41.0.2).

Comment: I might do that as last resort. I dont like to use two browsers.I open way to many tabs as is.

Answer (score 1):

After contacting Amazon, I was informed that since October 20 they no longer support Flash. They recommended installing Chrome (not Chromium), which will run the HTML5 player. That "solution" is working for me. Their support told me that currently no solution is available if you want to use Firefox in Ubuntu.