# no compatible source was found for this media

Tags: 18.04, firefox

I get this message,

> no compatible source was found for this media

when i try to watch anything on crunchyroll.

I cannot get any videos on reddit or Netflix either but YouTube is working fine.
I am using Firefox 64.0 and the sources work in chromium.

Videos were working earlier.

Edit:
Solved it by installing GStreamer Multimedia Codecs

Comment: post your edit as an answer...more reputation points

Answer (score 9):

1. Option 1:

   Try `sudo apt install libavcodec-extra`

   According to this answer:
   [Firefox html5 video support](https://askubuntu.com/questions/475351/firefox-html5-video-support)

   Restart Firefox when you are done.
2. Option 2:

   Installing GStreamer Multimedia Codecs

Comment: Option 1 worked for me. So haven't tried option 2.

Answer (score 4):

The media codecs for ubuntu are not installed by default.
Install the media codecs by

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```