# Firefox does not play videos (except for Youtube)

Tags: firefox

I have visited many sites offering solutions to this problem but nothing helps. I installed all the required codecs but the videos are not played.

For example, for for some videos there appears a message: *"No compatible source was found for this media."* or *"Unfortunately, this video is missing or damaged and cannot be played."*. Only YouTube videos are played fine. What is the issue and how to fix it?
The Ubuntu version is 20.04, and interestingly, Chrome has no such problems and can play all the videos.

Codecs installed:

```
sudo apt install libavcodec-extra
sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

Comment: Please edit the question and post your Ubuntu release/version and what codecs have you installed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [no compatible source was found for this media](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1105191/no-compatible-source-was-found-for-this-media)

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried it already and it doesn't work :(

Comment: Is your system fully updated? Does the same problem happen with different browsers? Do you have problems also with local files?

Comment: I can play all the videos with Chrome, and the system should be up-to-date.

Comment: The very likely the problem is unrelated to codecs or other software but with a corrupt Firefox user profile.

Answer (score 0):

Check journal entries. I had a similar problem and it was caused by AppArmor denying access to amdgpu drm lib.

`journalctl -xe -b` to check the logs

`sudo systemctl status apparmor.service` to check if AppArmor is running

I added this line `/opt/amdgpu/lib/**/*.so* mr,` to `/etc/apparmor.d/local/usr.bin.firefox` to allow access and it solved the problem.