# How can I watch videos online?

Tags: video, video-player

what app do i need to download in order to watch video's online? Something similar to flash program but for ubuntu? (first time ubuntu user)
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a web browser such as Firefox. It supports plugins to read videos like flash plugin.
You can read documentation about it [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FirefoxPlugins).
For some plugins you will need to play restricted format (see [How do I install ubuntu-restricted extras](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56446/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-restricted-extras))