# Install media codecs

Tags: 13.10, multimedia, codecs, ubuntu-restricted-extras

I tried to watch a movie but the Movie Player won't let me, and a screen popped up saying:

```
Videos requires to install plugins to play files of the following types: MPEG-1 Layer 3(MP3) decoder, MPEG-4 Video decoder
```

The pop up won't give me the choice to search for a package like other times and I don't know which to install or what command to use.

Comment: [install ubuntu restricted extras](http://askubuntu.com/questions/56446/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-restricted-extras)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Vlc Player , open terminal  :

```
 sudo apt-get update 

sudo apt-get install vlc
```

Comment: If I do this, do I still need to keep the Video Player default by Ubunto for some reason? If no, which command can I use to uninstall it?

Comment: you can keep it why you want to uninstall it

Comment: is it okay man , sounds good

Comment: welcome my friend any time

Answer (score 1):

as nux suggested you can use vlc. but if you prefer other programs you might need the Ubuntu restricted extras. Install them via the software center or with `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras`.

Comment: +1 to this - I would recommend doing this as well.