# How to install common media codecs

Tags: codecs

I'm new to Ubuntu. I tried installing it with Windows 8.1, but failed I lost all my files.

I have successfully formatted my PC and installed Ubuntu, but how do I install codecs to play audio and videos files ?

Comment: Videos codecs ? Audio codecs ?

Comment: Both I cant play audio cant play video even installed Mplayer with Software center i got response of skin problem..... its frustrating

Comment: possible duplicate of [Install media codecs](http://askubuntu.com/questions/430399/install-media-codecs-in-13-10)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>) and paste the following code :

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

Or install using Ubuntu Software center :

[image: Install via the software center]

It will install proprietary codecs needed for reading audio and video files.

---

Alternatively you can use VLC Media Player which can play most of the audio/video formats :

```
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

Comment: Got response  Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?

Comment: Do you have Ubuntu Software Center or another terminal open ?

Comment: Yes Since Mplayer isnt working i'm trying vlc

Comment: Vlc will work but will not install codecs on your system.

Comment: And how do i install other codecs

Comment: By doing what I said in my answer : 1) Close Ubuntu Software Center 2) Open a terminal and run ! sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras

Comment: Its downloading now i'm using and unreliable internet source, can i continue later incase network fails?

Comment: Yes you can re-run the command later.

Comment: Ok. I've accepted the answer related to command line terminal, and voted. thanks