# How can I play video or listen to music?

Tags: 14.04, multimedia

Recently I installed Ubuntu 14.04, now I am unable to play/listen to any music or video. I am a new user.

Comment: IF the suggested duplicate does not answer your question, please [edit] it and include more information about what you tried and why it does not work. Do you get any error messages?

Answer (score 2):

Open a terminal, and install the extra package, which includes codecs and other useful things and addons:

Before any install, update your software database with:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

If there is some packages ready to be updated, you can use:

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Then, continue with:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

To play music, install Rhythmbox if it is not included in the installation (it should be included):

```
sudo apt-get install rhythmbox
```

To play video, I suggest to use VLC media player, it have already a good quantity of codecs ready to play videos:

```
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

If you don't want to use the command line, just use the Ubuntu Software Center already included in the installation:

[Ubuntu Software Center](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/software-center/)

Comment: Oh, I din't notice it, thanks a lot for the corrections!. I will edit the answer with the update part. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Most of the common media codes can be found on `ubuntu-restricted-extras`. To install it, open a terminal (`Ctrl + Alt + T`) and paste the following code :

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

There are some media players than can play the most of the formats, like:

VLC media player. From the terminal (`Ctrl + Alt + T`), paste the following code :

```
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

Miro video player. From the terminal (`Ctrl + Alt + T`), paste the following code :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntuhandbook1/ppa
 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:joyard-nicolas/ffmpeg
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install ffmpeg miro
```

Source:  [How to install common media codecs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/656762/how-to-install-common-media-codecs)

Comment: Since there's only 3 minutes difference between first answer and yours @kek_kek I don't think this is overly important

Comment: @MarkKirby possibly kek_kek was composing his answer at the same time you posted the possible duplicate!

Comment: @kek_kek If you left before claiming people are attack you and now it is the same again, perhaps you should look at your self. This is not your hugbox, take the criticism, remove the answer and move on.

Comment: @kek_kek Downvotes are not personal, but they do reflect on the quality of your work and in this case your work is plagiarized.

Comment: @kek_kek Don't take things so personally, yes your edit add to the one you reference and that is fine, it is now your answer, in your words. If we just copy/paste other answers evey where, it will make a big mess :) I will change my vote and remove my comments.

Comment: Btw @mark kirby, as a high repo user commented me " ii) copying content from another answer on Ask Ubuntu is not plagiarism. Answers posted here are free to be copied and reused. Especially since kek_kek had included attribution". So I think in the end I was right.

Comment: I doubt they said that @kek_kek, you are wrong, it is NOT ok to copy / paste a question exactly, it is OK to reference it and use it as a source but you mu8st make it your own, that  is why this answer is now OK because you made it yours. I don';t know who this undisclosed user is but it is not OK http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78658/is-it-okay-to-copy-paste-answers-from-other-questions Ask a meta question about it, watch the result.