# Multiple graphics problems

Tags: graphics, mouse, themes, media, gnome-shell-extension

I've been toying around all day with ubuntu shell extensions and themes. I've now noticed that my mouse image is corrupted (i.e., the loading image above is stagnant) and my media players only play the audio and subtitles, but no image at all!
I've searched for a solution, but all I've found were indications to install restricted extras, which I already did a long time ago.

EDIT: I've also installed a Nvidea graphics driver

Comment: The Gnome-Tweak-Tool can help you install new Themes and you can pick a different icon pack. I personally love the Breeze Icon pack from the Breeze theme.

Comment: Additionally, you might want to try re-installing Gnome with `sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-shell`

Comment: I've already changed the theme. I don't think changing to the right theme will resolve the issue of not being able to play videos' image...

Comment: As for your video you may still need codecs. This can also be helped by trying a different media player like VLC. https://askubuntu.com/questions/656762/how-to-install-common-media-codecs

Comment: I reinstalled the shell and I've tried with other media players. Nothing worked... I've always used VLC and always worked, just stopped working now.