# Error installing ubuntu-restricted-extras

Tags: apt, system-installation, sudo

Ubuntu said I needed to install plugins using the following command in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

But then I got this error:

```
Reading package lists....Done
Building dependency tree
reading state information...Done
E:Unable to locate package Ubuntu-restricted
E:Unable to locate package extras
```

So,what to do now?

Answer (score 1):

From your error message:

```
Reading package lists....Done
Building dependency tree reading state information...Done
E:Unable to locate package Ubuntu-restricted
E:Unable to locate package extras
```

You missed the `-` between ubuntu-resticted and extras so ubuntu thinks of them as different packages instead of one package. That's why you're getting that error.

Try using this command instead:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu is case-sensitive (and space-sensitive), and you typed `Ubuntu-restricted extras` instead of `ubuntu-restricted-extras`. You should copy and paste the command to the terminal or install the package from the [Software Centre](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/ubuntu-restricted-extras/).

Answer (score 0):

On this page: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats, there is a link If you are using regular, stock Ubuntu: Click here to install the ubuntu-restricted-extras package. Have you tried clicking that to see if that would work?

Answer (score 0):

The thing is simple .. After fresh installation , do update by

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and then try installing it by -

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

May be you need to enable multi verse on Software and Update , [Click here to know the procedure.](https://askubuntu.com/a/340485/192102) make the change and then try update.