# Problem Installing MS fonts for Libre Office @ Ubuntu 14.04 codename Trusty

Tags: fonts

MY FIRST STEP IN THE TERMINAL:

```
aivinor@mcph:~$ sudo apt-get install ttf-mscorefonts-installer
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  imagemagick-common liblqr-1-0 libmagickcore5 libmagickcore5-extra
  libmagickwand5 libnetpbm10 linux-headers-3.13.0-32
  linux-headers-3.13.0-32-generic linux-image-3.13.0-32-generic
  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-32-generic netpbm
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  cabextract
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  cabextract ttf-mscorefonts-installer
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 32 not upgraded.
Need to get 70.6 kB of archives.
After this operation, 282 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
```

MY SECOND STEP:

```
 WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
          cabextract ttf-mscorefonts-installer
   Install these packages without verification? [y/N] y
   0% [Connecting to 172.16.19.10 (172.16.19.10)]
   Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe cabextract amd64 1.4-4
```

AT THIS POINT I FACE A NUMBER OF ERRORS THAT CLAIM INABILITY TO CONNECT TO 172.16.19.10 AS CONNECTION TIMED OUT - I HAVE NO INTERNET PROBLEMS 
SAYS FAILED TO FETCH AND HAS LINKS SUCH AS

```
in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/multiverse ttf-mscorefonts-installer all 3.4+nmu1ubuntu1
in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/c/cabextract/cabextract_1.4-4_amd64.deb

in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/multiverse/m/msttcorefonts/ttf-mscorefonts-installer_3.4+nmu1ubuntu1_all.deb
```

LAST LINE IS:

```
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Comment: From your errors seems you can't connect to a private IP address (probably your router). Have you already tried to run `sudo apt-get update`?

Comment: Thank you Danibix. What you have claimed seems to be true, if so how do I rectify this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be related with network connection.

So, first check if your PC is connected to your router:

```
ifconfig
```

The above command will show you PC network interfaces. Now look at the command output and search the `inet addr`. It should be in the second line of one of your connected interface (under something like `eth0` or `wlan0` depending if your are connected via cable or through WI-FI). If the value of your `inet addr` is similar to `172.16.x.x` your PC is in the same network of your router.

*If it is not so you have to reconnect to your router*. You can do this with Network Manager.

Now you can check the connection between your PC and your router with this command:

```
ping 172.16.19.10
```

If it works you can check connectivity with internet:

```
ping www.google.com -c 8
```

If also this works, you can install fonts as suggested by @mikeymop:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

---

If `ping` command didn't work it means 2 things:

1. ICMP packets cannot be sent over your network or out of it.
2. You can't reach your router or external server (e.g. www.google.com)

In the first case you could try to check your connectivity directly running

```
 apt-get update
```

In the other case you can try to reboot your router and you have to hope that all things will work after.

I hope this could help you.

Comment: I still have some problems, have identified that the inet addr for the router and laptop are different but im not too familiar with the network manager or how i can use it to fix this problem. Though i can connect to the internet the sudo apt-get update command gets stuck at 0%.

Comment: aivinor@mcph:~$ ping 172.16.19.10
PING 172.16.19.10 (172.16.19.10) 56(84) bytes of data.

there is no response after this

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried

```
$sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

[This package](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/ubuntu-restricted-extras), [includes the Microsoft fonts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56446/how-do-i-install-the-ubuntu-restricted-extras-package)

Comment: Thank you Mikey but the problem seems to be as Dani has mentioned above.