# Vlc and Smplayer not start

Tags: video, vlc, smplayer

If I run `vlc` from terminal I see

```
VLC media player 2.2.2 Weatherwax (revision 2.2.2-0-g6259d80)
[000000000130e148] core libvlc: Esecuzione di vlc con l'interfaccia predefinita. Usa 'cvlc' per utilizzare vlc senza interfaccia.
screen 0 does not appear to be DRI2 capable
screen 0 does not appear to be DRI2 capable
Errore di segmentazione (core dump creato)
```

If I run `smplayer` I see

```
screen 0 does not appear to be DRI2 capable
screen 0 does not appear to be DRI2 capable
Errore di segmentazione (core dump creato)`
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: Did you try opening through Dash ? What happens when you try ?

Comment: @user227495 nothing, it doesn't start

Comment: All display drivers in order ? Did you check " Additional Drivers " option through Dash ?

Comment: @user227495 Yes, nothing strange there

Comment: Can you try reinstalling display drivers ?

Comment: I removed amdgpu-pro drivers and now vlc works, but now I can't reproduce mkv videos

Comment: You mean you can't play them ?

Comment: Yes, I can open them, but the videos isn't fluently. It lags a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps to try

1. Reinstall display drivers
2. Check Additional Drivers from Dash for missing drivers
3. Install Ubuntu Restricted Extras from **Ubuntu Software Center**

This collection of packages includes:

MP3 and other audio codec software to play various audio formats (GStreamer plugins)

software to install the Microsoft Web fonts

the Adobe Flash plugin

LAME, software to create compressed audio files. This software does not include libdvdcss2, and will not let you play encrypted DVDs. For more information, see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats/PlayingDVDs

These software packages are from the Multiverse channel, restricted by copyright or legal issues in some countries. For more information, see http://www.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/licensing

**Ref** : http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/04/10-things-to-do-after-installing-ubuntu-16-04-lts

[How do I install the ubuntu-restricted extras package?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56446/how-do-i-install-the-ubuntu-restricted-extras-package)