# Could not play media on kubuntu installed on ASUS E200H

Tags: lubuntu, kubuntu, asus, media

I recently bought an *Asus E200H* that came pre-installed with Windows 10. Due to a storage problem, I installed Kubuntu 18.04 on the system after removing Windows 10.

But I am unable to play any media file (audio as well as video) on the laptop (including on *VLC* and *YouTube*). Whenever I try to play the video on youtube the video mostly just keeps on buffering and when the video starts it progresses with uneven speed(even though I have a high speed internet connection). The same happens on VLC but without any buffering. I am even uanble to play any mp3 files both online and offline files. I faced the same problem even after installing lubuntu on the system. I have even installed the ubuntu-restricted-extra-packages.

What can be the problem and how would I fix it?

Comment: Have you enabled the 'unfree' package-tree and installed the codec packages?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you expect to happen and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them *in their entirety* in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. Please **[edit]** your post to add information instead of posting a comment. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install the ubuntu-restricted extras package?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56446/how-do-i-install-the-ubuntu-restricted-extras-package)

Comment: Yes I have already installed the ubuntu-restricted extras packages but still the problem persists !!

Comment: Again: Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1076383/edit) your post to add information instead of posting a comment. And read: [How do I ask a good question?](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask)