# Firefox downloads the video instead of playing it

Tags: firefox

Totally a ubuntu beginner, for some site like https://learning.oreilly.com/ (it's an online book and video site for technical training and requires subscription) when I click to play a video, firefox always downloads the video instead of playing it. Youtube works fine though.

EDIT:
Just installed the chrome and the site works fine on chrome i.e. video plays as expected.

EDIT2:
The video format from the problematic site is mp4.

Comment: Is it spam?????

Comment: the video? No, the site is an online book and video store for training.

Comment: We can't check it. That must be the site setting.

Comment: It sounds like a feature of the site since it's a paid program. You could try installing plugins if the videos use a rare format.

Comment: I am trying to install chrome to see whether the site works.

Comment: YouTube embeds videos with an HTML5 player. That site might just embed the video files themselves.

Comment: Just installed the chrome and the site works fine on chrome.

Comment: What format are the videos in?

Comment: @RolandiXor mp4.

Answer (score 3):

After trying a number of things, finally installing `Ubuntu Restricted Extras` package and restarted Firefox fixed the issue.

See [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56446/how-do-i-install-the-ubuntu-restricted-extras-package) about how to install the package.

Hope this helps others who are like me just starting to use Firefox on Ubuntu.

Comment: There is a checkbox during installation that is about installing restricted formats. It is active by default. Do you remember if you maybe disabled it?

Comment: Honestly I can't remember. I am using Ubuntu on vmware; don't think I had to click much during the installation.

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed Chrome and the video is playing as expected it could be that the web browser that were using before is set to save video files instead of playing them on the web browser.

For instance, in [Firefox](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/change-firefox-behavior-when-open-file), there is a setting (under Preferences) General > Applications to specify default action for certain content types.

A similar question has been asked in [Mozilla support](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1196366), although the question pertains to Windows the solution is applicable to Ubuntu as well. You can reset Firefox Profile (if you are using Firefox) by uninstalling and deleting the profile directory (/home/USERNAME/.mozilla/ or ~/.mozilla) and then installing Firefox again. Note: You should make a backup of your Firefox Profile. You will also need to reinstall all the add-ons that you have installed before.

Comment: Just checked, I don't have default to download for mp4 or any video format. In fact I don't have any default for any video related applications.

Comment: Why would uninstalling firefox help at all in this case? I just have brand new Ubuntu install hence the firefox is as fresh as newly installed.

Comment: Apologies I have assumed that you are not using a fresh copy of Firefox since it was not mentioned on the question.