# Cannot play YouTube "Live" vidoes with Firefox 79.0 (64-bit)

Tags: 20.04, firefox, youtube, video-streaming

I cannot play YouTube "Live" vidoes with Firefox 79.0 (64-bit) on Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS. I tried to fix the issue by enabling "Play DRM controlled content" in Firefox settings and also installed ffmpeg "sudo snap install ffmpeg". I can watch regular YouTube videos just fine.

I installed Opera browser and have no trouble watching YouTube Live videos with Opera.

Here is a screenshot of the Youtube error I'm getting in Firefox:

[image]

Here is the debug info from YouTube:

```
 {"ns": "yt",
  "el": "detailpage",
  "cpn": "Tx5QLdN7fThRIw5R",
  "docid": "kPrbJ63qUc4",
  "ver": 2,
  "cmt": "0",
  "ei": "HMguYJnmG_vSzLUP_9a54A8",
  "fs": "0",
  "rt": "151.015",
  "of": "wbAUJoLFDaeeOSJrHXH1sg",
  "euri": "",
  "lact": 1,
  "live": "dvr",
  "cl": "357483374",
  "mos": 0,
  "osid": "MWU2OGVhM2U:AOeUNAZAby8qQi7W5tNRNSEaJAlTZYzG2Q",
  "state": "80",
  "vm": "CAEQABgEKiBEcTlDVDF2MFduMGJuR0ZYYzNKRElQaC1CU3JRRVdHaToyQU9HdF9PSlRnOHFvY1VjcVFJWEY1Z1I2ZlBBOEtDSmYxN19vZzR6QlpYQ2NMRTIwMVE",
  "volume": 100,
  "cbr": "Firefox",
  "cbrver": "79.0",
  "c": "WEB",
  "cver": "2.20210216.08.00",
  "cplayer": "UNIPLAYER",
  "cos": "X11",
  "cplatform": "DESKTOP",
  "delay": 5,
  "hl": "en_US",
  "cr": "US",
  "fexp": "23882578,23890959,23940248,23969934,23976578,23983297,23986034,23992809,23996624,23998149,24000883,24002247",
  "vct": "0.000",
  "vd": "NaN",
  "vpl": "",
  "vbu": "",
  "vpa": "1",
  "vsk": "0",
  "ven": "0",
  "vpr": "1",
  "vrs": "0",
  "vns": "0",
  "vec": "null",
  "vemsg": "",
  "vvol": "1",
  "vdom": "1",
  "vsrc": "0",
  "vw": "1280",
  "vh": "720",
  "debug_error": {
    "errorCode": "html5.unsupportedlive",
    "errorMessage": "This video format is not supported.",
    "Jx": "HTML5_NO_AVAILABLE_FORMATS_FALLBACK",
    "aj": "",
    "sG": "buildRej.1;a.1;d.1;drm.0;f18.0;c18.0;f133.1;f140.1;f242.0;cAVC.0;cAAC.0;cVP9.1;a6s.0"
  },
  "prerolls": "heartbeat",
  "ismb": 8840000,
  "latency_class": "ULTRALOW",
  "lowlatency": "1",
  "segduration": 1,
  "lat": 0,
  "relative_loudness": "NaN",
  "user_qual": "auto",
  "debug_videoId": "kPrbJ63qUc4",
  "0sz": false,
  "op": "",
  "yof": true,
  "dis": "",
  "gpu": "AMD_PITCAIRN_(DRM_2.50.0,_5.4.0-42-generic,_LLVM_10.0.0)",
  "cgr": true,
  "debug_playbackQuality": "unknown",
  "debug_date": "Thu Feb 18 2021 20:06:11 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)"
}
```

Comment: Firefox is currently v85.0.1 Why the old version?

Comment: m watching the NASA Mars Rover Youtube program on my Ubuntu PC with FF. Have you installed ubuntu-restricted-extras?   sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras

Comment: Installing the "ubuntu-restricted-extras" package seems to have solved the problem! It was a bit of a hassle as "sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras" doesn't work at first. You must enable multiverse in the Ubuntu "Software and Updates" app. [Detailed here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56446/how-do-i-install-the-ubuntu-restricted-extras-package) . Thanks!

Comment: I'll post as an answer, if you'd care to accept it it will help others looking for a solution to a similar problem. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OP found that by configuring Multiverse [reference here](https://itsubuntu.com/configure-universe-multiverse-and-restricted-repo-on-ubuntu-20-04-lts/) and installing ubuntu-restricted-extras:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

that the issue was resolved.