# Twitter ask por video codecs in Firefox

Tags: firefox, ffmpeg, codecs, drm, twitter

There is a similar question but none of the solutions does it for me.
I'm in a clean ubuntu 21.04install

Comment: Does it ask for a specific codec? Please edit the question and post the exact error message.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install the ubuntu-restricted-extras package?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56446/how-do-i-install-the-ubuntu-restricted-extras-package)