# dummy output or "no codecs found" on ubuntu 18.4

Tags: 18.04, sound

Sound stop working, possible after update.
Following instructions to fix it, I make following changes:
`sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`
Added at bottom: `options snd-hda-intel model=auto dmic_detect=0`
`sudo update-initramfs -u`

This doesn't help

Additional info:
`sudo cat /var/log/syslog | grep -A5 -B5 codec`

```
Nov 16 12:47:15 leo-pc kernel: [   48.689434] snd_hda_intel: unknown parameter 'dmic_detect' ignored
Nov 16 12:47:15 leo-pc kernel: [   48.689494] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
Nov 16 12:47:15 leo-pc kernel: [   48.689791] snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: Disabling MSI
Nov 16 12:47:15 leo-pc kernel: [   48.689794] snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: Handle vga_switcheroo audio client
Nov 16 12:47:15 leo-pc kernel: [   48.793041] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: CORB reset timeout#1, CORBRP = 0
Nov 16 12:47:15 leo-pc kernel: [   48.793136] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: no codecs found!
```

Update: HDMI sound also not working

This outputs hdmi sound cards. but not integral in motherboard.

```
aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 9: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

`leonid@leo-pc:~$ lsmod | grep snd_hda_intel`

```
snd_hda_intel          45056  2
snd_hda_codec         126976  2 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel
snd_hda_core           81920  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm               102400  4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_core
snd                    81920  13 snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_timer,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi
```

Comment: If you haven't yet done it  [How do I install the ubuntu-restricted-extras package?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56446/how-do-i-install-the-ubuntu-restricted-extras-package)

Comment: @24601 ubuntu-restricted-extras is already the newest version (66).

Comment: Probably its hardware problem. May be usb sound card will help. But it's strange internal audio and hdmi not working both